# Trying to set my Spring websocket run over TLS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, websocket

I have created a Spring websocket using Intellij community using Maven.
The websocket works, however it runs on HTTP, while I want it to run over TLS/SSL (HTTPS).

I've tried adding the below properties to the application.properties file (I have obtained a Certificate and created the keystore.JKS file, its path is the same path as the application.properties path):

```
# Enable HTTPS
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks 
server.ssl.key-store-password=*****
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

After running the application, nothing changed and the Tomcat still started on port 8080 (http).
I am struggling for days now on making my websocket run over TLS, and I would appreciate some assistance.
I would be happy to accept other suggestions for making my websocket run over TLS, instead of the application.properties file.

**My Spring websocket code:**

```
    package com.chess.web;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
    import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocket
    public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer{

        @Override
        public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry){
            registry.addHandler(new ChessWebSocketHandler(), "/chess").setAllowedOrigins("*");
        }
    }
```

```
    package com.chess.web;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class ChessGameApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            SpringApplication.run(ChessGameApplication.class,args);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably application is starting in https on 8080 if you open http://localhost:8080/ in browser you will see

[image: local https on port8080 called with http protocl]

if you go with https://localhost:8080/ will show the page, you may need to accept self signed certificate, example below
[image: https localhost]

you can find working code [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/local-ssl-websocket) for this test. And I took the chat system from [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/).